# Make fails with exit code "wait exited with error: No child processes"

Tags: linux, gnu-make

When compiling an application in a linux docker image with intel fortran and GNU Make 4.2.1 it often (but not always) fails with the following output:

```
[ 92%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/builds/HAWC2/HAWC2Lib/hawc2/source/aerodrag/aerodrag_calls.f90.o
     [ wait exited, unknown status 9 ]
wait exited with error: No child processes
Slots::
0:  active=T; pid=2327; status=0
    src=/builds/HAWC2/HAWC2Lib/hawc2/source/aeroload/aeroload_output.f90
    asm=(null)
    alt=/tmp/ifortWVMqH7as_.s
    obj=CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/builds/HAWC2/HAWC2Lib/hawc2/source/aeroload/aeroload_output.f90.o
    multisrc_src=(null)
    multisrc_clean=(null)
    driver_tempfile=/tmp/iforttempfileFKsbsq
1:  active=F; pid=0; status=0
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/build.make:655: CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/builds/HAWC2/HAWC2Lib/hawc2/source/aeroload/aeroload_output.f90.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/builds/HAWC2/HAWC2Lib/hawc2/source/aeroload/aeroload_output.f90.o'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: CMakeFiles/HAWC2Lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2
```

Why does it occur and how can I solve it?